# Disable parentheses autocomplete on Leetcode

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-developer-tools, browser-plugin

The in-browser Leetcode text editor autocompletes parentheses. (Typing '(' will automatically create a ')' in the text editor.) Unfortunately, Leetcode does not provide settings that disable this feature.

On [this page](https://leetcode.com/discuss/feedback/1951813/no-way-to-100-stop-auto-complete), a Leetcode user has suggested a fix:

> Solved it myself. Just copy-paste this into your browser's console:
> https://pastebin.com/DGW3sBZA. It will stop the auto-completion.

I can't figure out what to do this his code in either Firefox or Chrome.

If possible, how can I use his code to create a **permanent solution** to the parentheses problem? A permanent solution would persist across tabs, windows, and system restarts. If a permanent solution isn't possible, how can I use his code to create a **temporary solution** to the parentheses problem? Solutions in either Firefox or Chrome are welcome.

Comment: By `I can't figure out what to do this his code in either Firefox or Chrome.`, do you mean you don't know where to use this code? The browser's console they refer to is in DevTools which can be opened by `F12` and then click the Console tab. You should always evaluate any code before running it.

Comment: @MC10 yes, that is what I meant. With your instructions, I was able to run the code in the console. (although the pastebin code didn't work as intended). This is the temporary solution I was looking for. The remainder of the OP is asking how to make such a change permanent for the Leetcode website.

Comment: @user1735791 would you mind sharing the code that actually worked for you? Thanks.